# Запрос из браузера к базе данных через nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Пишу тестовое приложение на NodeJs, которое в связке с базой данных MySQL через Sequelize. Подскажите как сделать запрос из консоли браузера через fetch (или еще какой способ) чтобы получить данные из базы через ноду.

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
const sequelize = new Sequelize("usersdb", "root", "Vtldtlm007", {
  dialect: "mysql",
  host: "localhost",
});

const User = sequelize.define("user", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  age: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  User.findAll()
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

sequelize
  .sync()
  //.then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

Это нужно делать не через консоль браузера, а через софт вроде Postman например. Кстати Postman есть как в виде отдельной программы, так и в формате расширения для браузера.